# Malformed JSON response when parsing data

Tags: php, json, postman

Using Postman to see if this section of php works as intended, however Postman returns the error `Malformed JSON: Unexpected 'U'` and the database is not updated, can't get my head around this error as it looks fine to me?

Code:

```
function placeVoteForCandidate()
{
    global $connect;

    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $query = "UPDATE User SET votesAttained=votesAttained+1 WHERE USER_NAME = $username";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);

    $message['success'] = 'Vote added';
    echo json_encode($message);
}
```

Comment: How about some quotes around `$username`?

Comment: Yep, forgot that I needed to do that in PHP, cheers!

Comment: votesAttained=votesAttained+1  what is this ? 
votesAttained should be variable right?

Comment: Integer that should be incremented(like a Facebook 'like')

Comment: mmm...globals and ready to-get-injected-sql. Its party time. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing just

```
echo json_encode('Vote added');
```

there should be no problem. Is there any exception thrown causing this error?
Try to change the SQL statement to

```
$query = "UPDATE User SET votesAttained=votesAttained+1 WHERE USER_NAME = " . $username;
```

Comment: When I put quotes around the $username it worked fine, because the query was a string I just missed out the quotes without realising it, your way works perfectly as well though